# How to show overall usage of system resources in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is there any way that i can see all system resources usage together in terminal, as we see on windows platform under `Resource Monitor`. I can see each resource usage under Linux separately, but i need to show all resources parallel so that i can compare each process in terms of usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute **top** from within terminal.

There are some specific arguments you can pass to it as well: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

Answer (score 4):

There are some tools to show overall usage of system resources like e.g. `top`. However there are more appropriate tools. One of those is `atop`. In contrast to `top` `atop` shows also networking and disk informations. And has also more filtering possibilities.

See also http://www.atoptool.nl/index.php

Comment: It's a little strange that it starts a daemon, but the data it collects and presents is probably worth it. Thanks!